# Magento 2 Extension - lib folder or through composer

Tags: extensions, magento-2.1, 3rd-party-library

I am using a third party module for Mailchimp. I've been able to install it through composer and also used it through directory lib in the magento 2 root.

As installing through composer is quite cumbersome task, therefore I was looking whether it will be ok to add my 3rd party library in lib folder for creating an extension to sell it on magento's market place.

Comment: As mentioned, I've been able to install it through composer but the question is whether to use it through composer or directly putting in lib directory ?